# Вывод результата кода

Tags: python

Всем привет! У меня есть задание: поменять первую и последнюю букву местами в каждом слове из имеющегося списка

```
lst = 'Castle', 'Dog', 'Girlfriend'
result = []
for i in lst:
    result.append(i[-1] + i[1:-1] + i[0])
    print(result)
```

В моём результате, компилятор выводит на экран три строки с каждым элементом, а нужно только одну.

```
['eastlC']
['eastlC', 'goD']
['eastlC', 'goD', 'dirlfrienG']
```

Где ошибка?

Comment: вы же сами делаете список и выводите его после каждого добавления

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = 'Castle', 'Dog', 'Girlfriend'
result = []
for i in lst:
    result.append(i[-1] + i[1:-1] + i[0])
print(", ".join(result))
```

Выводит - `eastlC, goD, dirlfrienG`,

чтобы выводилось через пробел замените последнюю строку

на `print(*result)`, и ещё

если нужно вывести в виде списка - `print(result)` ( тоже заменить последнюю строку )

Comment: 'чтобы выводилось через пробел' print(*result)

Comment: @СергейШ, так тоже можно, но я его использую в функциях, это уже на усмотрение. Добавил вашу рекомендацию.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = 'Castle', 'Dog', 'Girlfriend'
result = []
# проход по "списку" и вывод
for i in lst:
    result.append(i[-1] + i[1:-1] + i[0])

print(result)
```